# How to match list of elements of a row, with values in a spark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two large date frames dictionary-frame and input-frame. I want to check the dictionary-frame against the input.

```
class_dictionary = pd.DataFrame( {   
    'Subject' :   ["qqq", "rrr", "sss", "ttt", "uuu"],
    'Class'    : ["A type",    "B type",   "C type",  "C type",   "A type"],
    })
class_dictionary
    
    Subject     Class
0   qqq     A type
1   rrr     B type
2   sss     C type
3   ttt     C type
4   uuu     A type
```

And my input frame is,

```
input_db = pd.DataFrame( {   
    'Obj' :   ["name1", "name2", "name3", "name5",  "name10million"],
    'Subject List'    : ["qqq, ttt, ZZZ(not in the dict)",    "qqq, ttt, sss",   "uuu",  "rrr",   "uknown"],
    })
input_db

    Obj     Subject List
0   name1   qqq, ttt, ZZZ(not in the dict)
1   name2   qqq, ttt, sss
2   name3   uuu
3   name5   rrr
4   name10million   uknown
```

And output should look like similar to this,

```
sample_output = pd.DataFrame( {   
    'Obj' :   ["name1", "name2", "name10million"],
    'Values'    : ["qqq, ttt, ZZZ(not in the dict)", "qqq, ttt, sss", "uknown"],
    'Calculated (can be different new columns)' : ["A type: qqq, C type: ttt", "A type: qqq, C Type: ttt, C type: sss", "unk"],
    'Count of types' : ["2", "2", "0"]
    })
sample_output

     Obj    Values-Calculated (can be different new columns)          Count of types
0   name1   qqq, ttt, ZZZ(not in the dict)  A type: qqq, C type: ttt         2
1   name2   qqq, ttt, sss   A type: qqq, C Type: ttt, C type: sss            2
2   name10million   uknown  unk                                              0
```

I know a very lazy way of doing this using python, which is not solving my problem. I want to be able to do this using pyspark.

I know its relatively complex, any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split and explode the subject list, then join the dataframes and do an aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(class_dictionary)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(input_db)

result = df2.withColumn(
    'Subject', 
    F.explode(F.split('Subject List', ', '))
).join(
    df1, 
    'Subject', 
    'left'
).groupBy('Obj', 'Subject List').agg(
    F.collect_list(
        F.when(
            F.col('Class').isNotNull(), 
            F.struct('Class', 'Subject')
        )
    ).alias('Calculated'), 
    F.countDistinct('Class').alias('Count of types')
)

result.show(truncate=False)
+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|Obj          |Subject List                  |Calculated                                   |Count of types|
+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
|name10million|uknown                        |[]                                           |0             |
|name2        |qqq, ttt, sss                 |[[A type, qqq], [C type, ttt], [C type, sss]]|2             |
|name3        |uuu                           |[[A type, uuu]]                              |1             |
|name5        |rrr                           |[[B type, rrr]]                              |1             |
|name1        |qqq, ttt, ZZZ(not in the dict)|[[C type, ttt], [A type, qqq]]               |2             |
+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a million. Interestingly, in the output, I a getting the value in a different format, looks like this  [{A type, qqq}, {C, E..  -- that means a list of dict. Why?

Second question, is it possible to get a separate column say, "Types_in_calculated_column" where the value will be like, 

1) A type 

2) A type, C type 

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, those are structs (dictionaries in spark), but they're displayed in square brackets when you call `df.show()`. If you want separate column you can select `Calculated.Class` as a new column

Comment: Thank you. But Calculated.Class returns a dataframe. so cannot add as column with withColumn. Says, "AssertionError: col should be Column"

Comment: df.withColumn('newcol', F.col('Calculated.Class'))?

Comment: What an idiot am I? Kept trying 
result.withColumn("new_col", result.select("Calculated.Class"))
You have already given a lot of help, would you mind asking,
Is there way for python set() like operation only to get the unique values?

Comment: try `F.array_distinct(F.col('calculated.class'))`